# Using the Material Drawer component in an Angular app

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material, drawer, mdc-components

How do I integrate the Material Drawer component in an Angular app? I cannot get it to render properly using the instructions in https://material.io/develop/web/components/drawers/

Can some one provide step-by-step instructions to make mdc-drawer work as shown in the demo?

Comment: You are probably looking for Angular Material https://material.angular.io/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do like this step by step.

**step 1** :- 
install angular material using this command `npm install @angular/material` in your project.

**step 2** :- 
add this in your index.html header

`<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">`

**step 3** :-
import below modules in your app.modules.ts or your root module file.

```
import { MatSidenavModule } from '@angular/material/sidenav';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { MatIconModule } from '@angular/material/icon';
```

**step 4** :-
add these modules in `imports` array.

**step 5** :-
add this in you html file.

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="example-container" *ngIf="shouldRun">
  <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="side" [(opened)]="opened" (opened)="events.push('open!')"
               (closed)="events.push('close!')">
    Sidenav content
  </mat-sidenav>

  <mat-sidenav-content>
    <mat-toolbar color="primary">
      <mat-toolbar-row>
        <mat-icon aria-hidden="false" aria-label="Example home icon" (click)="sidenav.toggle()">menu</mat-icon>
        <span>Custom Toolbar</span>
      </mat-toolbar-row>
    </mat-toolbar>
    <p>Events:</p>
    <div class="example-events">
      <div *ngFor="let e of events">{{e}}</div>
    </div>
  </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

**step 6** :-
add this in you ts file.

```
events: string[] = [];
opened: boolean;

shouldRun = [/(^|\.)plnkr\.co$/, /(^|\.)stackblitz\.io$/].some(h => h.test(window.location.host));
```

**step 7** :-
add this in your component scss file.

```
.example-container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
}
```

**step 8** :-
add this in you style.scss file.

```
@import '~@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/deeppurple-amber.css';
```

please check [working demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-side-navigation)

If you still face any issue, do let me know.

Comment: the tag described in the example is <aside>